# Update Textarea value with ID instead of using ng-model in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can use the below code snippets to update the value of one textarea with another simultanoeusly

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <input id="id1" type="text">

       <input id="id2" type="text">
     </div>
   </div>

Script file:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.text1 = '';

  }]);
```

Is there a way I can use the ID to update the value simultanously instead of the ng-model property. Thank you!!!

Comment: Check updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('text1', function () {
    document.getElementById('id2').value = $scope.text1;
});
```

Comment: Can I do this only using the id property. Check my updated question

Comment: I dont want to make use of ng-model

Comment: why don't use ng-model? what reason?

Comment: ng-model value for the textarea is coming from a sensitive third party library!

Comment: Did you try to create angular service for that library?